# How do I compare datetimes in SQL so that equal dates are excluded?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a statement setup as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Events
WHERE CAST('6/6/2013 10:14:30 PM' AS DATETIME) < EventTime
```

Right now, it returns every event including those occurring at that time, which means I have to process the events after the query.  Is there a way to setup this query so that it only returns events with an `EventTime` that is greater than the given string datetime?

Basically, the `<` operator seems to be treated as `<=`, and I don't want this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9cb8a/12/0

Comment: Could you provide sample 'EventTime' values?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Probably `EventTime` has milliseconds accuracy: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9cb8a/17

Comment: (1) Please don't use string literals like m/d/y or d/m/y = for one, if that was 7/6/2013, I would have no idea if you meant July 6 or June 7, and SQL Server may pick one of the other based on a variety of settings that may be outside of your control. Use YYYYMMDD always. (2) Why `expression < column` when what you clearly want to express in English is `column > expression`? (3) Can you show some actual values in the table that are "occurring at that time" so we can see exactly what "that time" is in terms of the data stored?

Comment: (4) Are you sure the underlying data type of `EventTime` is `DATETIME`? Perhaps it is rounding because it is `SMALLDATETIME` or something else is going on because it's a string...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function of sql server, like such:

```
SELECT *
FROM Events
WHERE DATEDIFF(Second, Cast('6/6/2013 10:14:30 PM' AS DATETIME) , @EventTime) < 0 
             --^^ this can be changed to what ever accuracy you want
```

Answer (score 0):

First  your string date type is ambigous: you either need to use `6 JUN 2013` as the date part or `JUN 6 2013` or `YYYY/MM/DD HH:NN:SS` actually it goes to milliseconds.

Also you may not be getting full use of your indexes on `EventTime` as depending on the version of SQL: `EventTime > CAST('6/6/2013 10:14:30 PM' AS DATETIME)` is not evaluated in the same way as `CAST('6/6/2013 10:14:30 PM' AS DATETIME) < EventTime`

If `EventTime` evaluates as `2013/6/6 10:14:30.001` then SQL is operating correctly. You may want to use `DATEDIFF(Seconds, EventTime, '2013/6/6 10:14:30') > 0` (may be less than) this will evaluate the number of boundaries crossed. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

I suspect you want `2013/6/6 10:14:31` to be returned which crosses 1 second boundary.